# Asynchronous execution in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, jms

I'm learning Java EE currently (moving from SE) and I am confused about asynchronous execution in Java EE environment.
Basically what I understand creating `Thread` or `Timer` is not exactly recommended. One other method what I found so far are use JMS for transfer message to EJB Message Bean and it will be executed asynchronously.

What are some other methods to achieve this behavior? Cause using JMS looks like too much overhead for simple tasks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest possible solution in Java EE 6 is to use [`@Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation on your EJB method (or the whole class). It allows you to invoke a business method asynchronously which means that a new thread will be delegated to execute this method and you'll get the control back in caller method.

In pre-Java EE 6 days the JMS was used for this purpose.

As a side note - in [Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#asyncSupported%28%29) you can also use asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [spring task executor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Other jobs may be putting it in a database and execute a task that is polling the database.

For large applications you could even consider using an Enterprise Service Bus.

It all depends on how important that tasks are and what efforts you are willing to do.

For not so important tasks simple Threads will often do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, asynchronous behavior is achieved with threads, there's no getting around that.

However, in a Java EE environment it's considered a bad practice to open threads by yourself. Most likely you'll want to use your server's facility that will give you a (properly) managed environment for doing async stuff.

JMS is one way of doing async tasks, I would recommend that for task streams that need to be continuously processed. Most Java application servers have scheduling managers which allow you to schedule single tasks in the future (e.g. via quartz). Some frameworks also support the Java EE 6 annotations for `@javax.ejb.Asynchronous`.

And yes, if you must, you can always just spawn a single `Thread` and forget about it all. Just make sure you know what you're doing.

It all boils down to what your exact use-case is, and which methods your environment supports. There's no one single true answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Java EE 6 and Spring enthusiasts have spoken; somehow everyone have left off the `javax.ejb.TimerService` from Java EE 5, which, I'll venture a guess, is currently [as of 2011] the predominant platform.

Basically, you inject the `TimerService` in your *stateless* or *message-driven* bean, and use one of its `createTimer(...)` methods to schedule the asynchronous execution. Then you implement the timeout logic in an annotated method:

```
@Timeout
void anyMethod(javax.ejb.Timer timer) { ... }
```

And that's that. Using JMS only for the sake of its asynchronous nature has never been a good option, unless as long time ago as in J2EE.

Comment: I _think_ I see what you mean: TimerService has been available since EJB 2.1 and J2EE 1.4, so prior to Java EE 6 TimerService was a reasonable option for asynchronous execution versus JMS. I'm not sure what you mean by "Using JMS only for the sake of its asynchronous nature has never been an option", unless you mean "has never been [a good] option". In any case I'm glad @Asynchronous is now available, as both JMS and TimerService include features we don't need for this specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I might have meant what you said; the answer is 3 years old and I only vaguely remember my thinking. Anyway, I needed to revert one change by Arjan Tijms, as he changed the meaning of my post.